# Send E-Mail when value=J in the same row, different column

Tags: vba, excel

I've the following code, which calls the function SendSingleMail as long as there is an email adress found in column 22, V.

```
Cells(2, 22).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = ""

    strEmailTo = ActiveCell.Value
    SendSingleMail (strEmailTo)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
```

I'm trying to add a second loop, which points to column 6, F: In this column I've either "J" or "N" (Yes/No) to determine if an email has to be sent for every row.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to modify your code as follows. Substitute "put_row_number_here" with the row number where you want to start and substitute "put_column_number_here" with the column where you want to start.

```
Cells(put_row_number_here, put_column_number_here).Select

Do Until ActiveCell = ""
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0,4).Value = "J" Then
        strEmailTo = ActiveCell.Value
        SendSingleMail (strEmailTo)
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
Loop
```

Comment: I dont think ive made myself clear here:
I want to start with Cells (2,22). Select, because all email adresses are stored in column 22.
I now need to modify the vba code to "look" in column 6: For example if there is an email adress in cell (4, 22) and a "J" in cell (4, 6) an email should be send.
If there is an "N" for that row number, the email function doesnt get called and the script continues.